# How to define F_CPU for external libraries?

Tags: c++, c, avr

I want to write library for avr which uses <util/delay.h> and it requires F_CPU to be defined, so i faced the problem, is there any way in C/C++ for libraries to get defines for attributes which user writes in main file? I guess the question is kinda dumb, since libraries compiles first, then the main file. I've come to a solution with using init.h file, which contains user initial setups, still doesn't solve the problem with already compiled libraries. Still, maybe there are some other workarounds or standardized approach for this type of problem. here's the code:

main.cpp

```
#include "myLib.h"
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>


int main(){
    DDRD = 0xFF;
    PORTD = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        blink();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

init.h

```
#pragma once 
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
```

myLib.h

```
#pragma once 
#include "init.h"
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void blink();
```

myLib.cpp

```
#include "myLib.h"

void blink(){
    PORTD ^= 0xFF;
    _delay_ms(500);
}
```

Comment: That should define the macro you specified. What exactly is the compilation error you get?

Comment: @yeputons , the build is without any errors and works fine, i just wanted to know if this approach is generally a good practice in programming in C/C++ and how this is usually done, im kinda new in programming

Comment: Not sure, it's some Arduino-specific stuff. I'в expect `F_CPU` to be specified in the compilation settings (`-DF_CPU=16000000UL`) so it's automatically passed to all files in the project. But it's a matter of taste/traditions. Do as good Arduino projects do, I think.

Comment: Your init.h solution is fine, though config.h is a more normal name for it.  If you need to support multiple boards with same source code in the future, I recommend defining macros on the command line like this: `-DF_CPU=16000000` .

Comment: @dummygum If you want to keep macro definition in a header file for some reason (e.g. it is automatically generated from another file) and include it to all files you can use `-include` gcc option.

Comment: To work with 1MHz and 8MHz I compile two times the library, generating two differents libraries: for instance `libavr_1000000UL.a` and `libavr_8000000UL.a`. [Here](https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/src/avr/make.sh) you can find an example, and [here](https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/mk/mcu_genrules.mk) the compilation rules I use.

Answer (score 0):

In your Makefile add `-DF_CPU=16000000UL` to the `C_FLAGS`.

Adding `-DF_CPU` to `C_FLAGS` is how this is commonly done.

Comment: Conventional name for C flags is `CFLAGS`. But `CPPFLAGS` (C preprocessor flags) is better to use for command line macro definitions as it is passed for both C and C++ by implicit make rules, and for compilation stage only, not linker.