# Issue related to delay in ATmega4809 Curiosity Nano Board

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, avr, atmega, microchip

I'm new to "ATmega4809 Curiosity Nano Board", I was trying the simple Blinking of LED with a delay of 1second. But the delay which i achieved is 1.24seconds.

How do I regulate this ? Please suggest how to regulate the delay exactly?

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/system/system.h"
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/*
    Main application
*/

int main(void)
{
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    LED0_SetDigitalOutput();

    while(1)
    {
        LED0_SetLow();
        _delay_ms(1000);
        LED0_SetHigh();
        _delay_ms(1000);

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That would depend entirely on the implementation of `_delay_ms()`. No doubt the clock frequency that is defined for is not the clock frequency you are running at.

The solution is to set the correct value for `F_CPU` as described in [the documentation](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html). The ATMega4809 [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/Atmega809-1609-3209-4809-48-Pin-40002016C.pdf) shows clock options for either 16 or 20 MHz.  Yours is clearly running slower than `F_CPU` used to calculate delays (20/16 = 1.25 - your measured 1.24 is within the +/-2% precision for the internal oscillator). Either select the higher clock rate option or modify `F_CPU`.  Noting that the actual frequency is subject to a prescaler in
`MCLKCTRLB` that defaults to 6, (see [MegaAVR 0-series manual](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/megaAVR0-series-Family-Data-Sheet-DS40002015B.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjTtaLGhrCDAxXQU0EAHRvMBCgQFnoECBEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3MMI7Ug099tLLQ0HAVPANM) section 9.3.3) so the correct `F_CPU` value is either 16000000/6 or 20000000/6.

So to correct for 16MHz internal oscillator and default prescaler:

```c
#include "mcc_generated_files/system/system.h"

#undef F_CPU
#define F_CPU (16000000 / 6)

#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/*
    Main application
*/

int main(void)
{
    ...
```

It is possible that `F_CPU` is set in system.h where you should probably correct it in preference to the brute force override as above.  I guess the file is generated by some project configuration where you should correct it rather than the file itself.  It may alternatively be  set using a `-D` command-line definition.  Wherever it is defined, correct it.

A note of caution should you consider increasing the frequency by changing the prescaler. The maximum permitted frequency is supply voltage dependent according to Table 4-3 in the datasheet.  Further the Curiosity Nano is factory set to 3.3V, so you should not exceed 10MHz, without first selecting the 5V supply.  If you exceed the "safe" frequency, your part may fail to start.

Comment: Note I have not used this board, or this MCU.  I have simply read the documentation. Hence all the links. Nothing  has been tested by me, not all solution details are necessarily correct or complete (but the diagnosis certainly is).

Comment: Should probably also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74977841/how-to-define-f-cpu-for-external-libraries with respect to setting F_CPU so that it applies to all translation units in a project.

Comment: Hi, I tried "#undef F_CPU
#define F_CPU (16000000 / 6)" still the delay remains the same... I also tried this statement "_PROTECTED_WRITE(CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLB, 0<<CLKCTRL_PEN_bp);" But the delay is reducing to 200ms , but the set delay timing is 1s.

Comment: @Asha then then clearly FREQSEL=1 and you should use `#define F_CPU (20000000 / 6)`.  avr/delay.h simply includes util/delay.h and is a backward compatibility file. You need include only the latter.  Disabling the prescaler would result in a clock of either 16MHz or 20MHz (omit the divide by 6). As I mentioned, setting a clock > 10MHz is not guaranteed to work at 3.3V. Did you also adjust the voltage?

Comment: @Asha since the default is 1MHz, clearly it is being set to 2.666667MHz somewhere in your build.  That is where you should change it (to 3.333333MHz) in preference to the override.